# Linux .SH Programs

Tags: linux, sh

I just like to ask if anyone here knows how to automatically start a **.sh** program in Linux on a daily basis.
This is because I have a server running which runs untill a certain point at midnight then stops. I'd like to have a program that can automatically restart it at a certain time every day.

Comment: Have a look at [cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron).

Answer (score 0):

you can automatically run the script by using the cron deamon

First you have to add the command to cron

```
crontab -e //this will open a file with your default editor
//to this file add your command at last
```

command syntax:

```
* * * * * * /home/loc/shell.sh  //runs every minuite

ex */45**** /home/loc/shllscript.sh  // runs every 45 mins
```

Answer (score 0):

cron will do what you need to do.

The first line will start your script at 2:30 every day. The second line will stop it at 12:00

```
30 2 * * * myscript.sh 
00 12 * * * killall myscript.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also refer to "at", which can run jobs at certain time period